# Probability of passing a test using completely random answers.

Tags: probability

> Let's say we have an exam with 40 questions. Each question has one good answer out of four. You pass the exam if you have at least 20 questions answered correctly. What's the probability of passing it by choosing completely random answers?

I'd say that favorable outcomes could be calculated using combinations:

${40}\choose{20}$+${40}\choose{21}$+...+${40}\choose{40}$

It seems quite strenuous, though.

What about elementary events? First thing, which comes to my mind is $40!$, but I'm not sure.

Comment: "Each question has one good answer". How many wrong answers, instead? Without knowing how many options has each question, you cannot say anything.

Comment: If you know the probability of getting one question correct, you can model this with a Binomial Distribution.

Comment: a normal approximation is almost certainly good enough, but as others have remarked, the problem is impossible without knowing the probability of getting a specified question right.

Comment: Let's say that there are 4 answers for each question, so 3 are wrong.

Comment: I think you should edit your post to include the number of options for each question.

Answer (score 0):

So, I've choosen to do this using binomial distribution. The graph sheds some light.

[image: binomial distribution graph]

It shows that with 40 questions and 4 answers for each one, it's practically impossible to pass a test with random answers. Initially, I thought there may be some bigger probability.

For >26 it's basically 0,0000000, so rounding to 7 digits we can say it's approximately **0,0005724**